# PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target?

Tags: java, https, tomcat7, directoryservices, pkix

I created a local keystore with keytool using java and done ssl configuration in Apache Tomcat.

I have been installed certificate in my local machine, even added to the jre cacerts as a trustedentry.

opening through browser via https is working fine[image]

But the problem is while trying to access through directory services.

```
error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the issue resolved by finding out the correct JRE and adding the certificate as trusted entry.

> Working with browser is fine since the browser knows that the
>   certificate is trusted but **JRE** is dumb in this case. So, need to
>   add the certificate as trusted entry to the `cacerts` keystore of the
>   correct JRE(When we have multiple JREs installed on our system).